# React native: [Branch] customMetadata values must be strings

Tags: react-native, branch.io

When I am using branch.io deep linking to my react native application. I am getting this error:

```
[Branch] customMetadata values must be strings. Value for property 0 has type object.
Value for 0 cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String

[Branch] customMetadata values must be strings. Value for property amount has type number.
```

with this issue application is crashed. how can I solve this issue?

Code snippets:

```
let branchObject: Function | undefined;

const logEvent = async (event: string, customData: any) => {
  if (!branchObject) branchObject = await BranchIO.createBranchUniversalObject('commonIdentifier');

  new BranchEvent(event, branchObject, { customData }).logEvent();
};
```

Comment: You can see this link https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native

Comment: Please attach code snippets as well of your BUO

Comment: I updated the question!